# Before I do this by hand, is there a nice gem/easy way to include things like ratings, favourites, etc. in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rating, favorite

I guess it's not so hard to do this by hand, but I was curious if there was easy ways to include concepts like "Ratable" or "Favouritable" and so on. It's really easy to do by hand I guess, but there are tag libraries for this sort of thing that also provide scopes, tag clouds and the correct migrations with the right indexing strategies... so I thought maybe there might be a similar thing that is all encompassing since these things are basically the same idea.

Comment: I would have suggested looking at http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_ratings.html , but none of the projects there look too active.

Comment: I always find it hard to search for gems. Even if you see a gem with a lot of activity, it could just be a self-fulfilling prophecy and the gem isn't that good. It's better to ask people in the field honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thumbs_up](https://github.com/tomoya55/thumbs_up) and [Ajaxful rating](https://github.com/siannopollo/ajaxful-rating) are good solutions of this problem. Successfully used in my applications.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the Make Votable gem:
https://github.com/medihack/make_voteable